# Angular7 FullCalendar error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I am trying out [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io) version 4.3 on a clean Angular 7.2.0 application. I am following [this official guide](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular). When I load a simple empty calendar, it works fine. As soon as I add any events AND the event should be displayed, it throws an error without displaying the event.

full calendar with events (copied from documentation):

```
<full-calendar
  defaultView="dayGridMonth"
  [plugins]="calendarPlugins"
  [weekends]="false"
  [events]="[
    { title: 'event 1', date: '2019-08-06' },
    { title: 'event 2', date: '2019-08-07' }
  ]"
></full-calendar>
```

Error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at DayGridView.push../node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.esm.js.View.computeEventDraggable (main.esm.js:7575)
    at DayGridEventRenderer.push../node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.esm.js.SimpleDayGridEventRenderer.renderSegHtml (main.esm.js:218)
    at DayGridEventRenderer.push../node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.esm.js.FgEventRenderer.renderSegEls (main.esm.js:7799)
    at DayGridEventRenderer.push../node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.esm.js.FgEventRenderer.renderSegs (main.esm.js:7763)
    at DayGrid.res [as renderFgEvents] (main.esm.js:3183)
    at DayGrid.push../node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.esm.js.DayGrid.render (main.esm.js:742)
    at DayGrid.push../node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.esm.js.Component.receiveProps (main.esm.js:3881)
    at SimpleDayGrid.push../node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.esm.js.SimpleDayGrid.render (main.esm.js:1518)
    at SimpleDayGrid.push../node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.esm.js.Component.receiveProps (main.esm.js:3881)
    at DayGridView.push../node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.esm.js.DayGridView.render (main.esm.js:1584)
```

Comment: This looks identical to this: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4297
It looks like the resolution involved updating the fullcalendar component source :/

Comment: "date" isn't a valid property for an event (it's documented in the "event object" documentation page). Set "start" instead (and also "end" if necessary) to define when the event occurs. I think that Angular documentation page maybe has a typo

Comment: actually it does work with either date or start+end. I think i had some missing import or plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this example angular project](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/tree/master/angular) on github which works fine. I recreated the project from scatch, updating the FullCalendar version to 4.3.0 (latest) without any problems. I can't figure out what went wrong in the original app, however if anyone's having trouble getting it to work, the example project will help.